# Test for nonlinearity of regression model with ARIMA errors in R?

Tags: regression, arima, nonlinearity

I would like to do regression with ARIMA errors in R with `TropBirds.ts` as response variable and `ForFrag.ts` as explanatory variable:

```
arima(TropBirds,order=c(p,d,q), xreg=ForFrag)
```

According to both [Keenan](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/72/1/39.short) and [Tsay](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2336223?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) tests, `TropBirds.ts` is a non-linear time series, and `ForFrag` is a linear time series.

Is it sound to do the proposed regression given the non-linearity of `TropBirds.ts`? If not, is there a way to fix this issue, e.g. transform `TropBirds.ts` into a linear time series? I've tried Box-Cox transformation, it didn't work.

If it is OK to go ahead with the proposed regression, is there a package to test for nonlinearity of the regression models with ARIMA errors in R? `Keenan.test` and `Tsay.test` from TSA package do not seem to support this option.

**References**

- Keenan, Daniel MacRae. ["A Tukey nonadditivity-type test for time series nonlinearity."](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/72/1/39.short) *Biometrika* 72.1 (1985): 39-44.
- Tsay, Ruey S. ["Nonlinearity tests for time series."](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2336223?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) *Biometrika* 73.2 (1986): 461-466.